# iOS go to specific tabbar-view from another view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tabbar

I have 5 views with a button and a tabbar controller that contains 5 views. I am not using the storyboard. I want to go from my views to a specific tabbar-view. When I create a segway to the destination view, the tabbar is not included.

I've tried to use the

```
-(IBAction)goHome {
    tabController.selectedIndex = 1;
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:tabController animated:YES];
}
```

method. But it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You asked a very similar question yesterday. I never got a good answer from you then on what your app structure is. It's impossible to answer this question without more detail. Are you setting up all these controllers in the app delegate? If so post the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you forgot to define all the class name and NIB name of tabbar (that you want to show particular view) in the XIB utilities , and make sure taht should be the same also